# How to retrieve picklist option values in heroku

Tags: picklist, schema, heroku, heroku-connect

I am trying to get and display the picklist option from salesforce, in heroku. Can anyone kindly let me know how I can achieve this.

I am querying records from case. And I want to display the case origin options.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a `GET` request to the [SObject Describe](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_describe.htm) REST Endpoint. The large [response body](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_describe.htm) includes all the information you'd expect in Apex from the `DescribeSobjectResult` and `DescribeFieldResult` classes.

> GET /services/data/v44.0/sobjects/Account/describe

yields a response body including

```
{
    "name" : "Type",
    "picklistValues" : [ 
        { "active" : true, "defaultValue" : false, "label" : "Prospect", "validFor" : null, "value" : "Prospect" }, 
        { "active" : true, "defaultValue" : false, "label" : "Customer - Direct", "validFor" : null, "value" : "Customer - Direct" },
        ...
      ],
      ...
}
```

as part of the list under the key `fields`. Much data is omitted above for brevity.

Alternately, consider using the [UI API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_get_started.htm) to get back fully-formed details of how to render the user interface for a specific record, including picklist details.